# openfiledialog, open already in use textfile

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

Been searching a while and can't seem to find any answer to my problem.
I want to be able to open a file which is already in use. This is the code I use to open the file with:

```
OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();


openFile1.Filter = "Text Files|*.log";
openFile1.Multiselect = true;
openFile1.Title = "Open log files";

if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

_textArray = richTextBox1.Lines;
```

Comment: You can try to copy the file first and then open the copy but if that also fails you're out of luck.

Comment: Have a look there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709104/how-do-you-read-a-file-which-is-in-use

Comment: Is this a log file generated by log4net, by any chance?  I recently solved a similar problem by configuring log4net with `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />`

Comment: No its a chatlog from a game im trying to read while the game uses it

Comment: @Winkz, have you tried shared read , posted below, this might help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this unless the other entity which has the file open allows for shared reads.  Therefore, you must open the filestream with the FileShare.ReadWrite parameter.

There are some already answers to this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx
[Exception in opening a file that is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846646/exception-in-opening-a-file-that-is-already-open)
[How do I open a file that is opened in another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048225/how-do-i-open-a-file-that-is-opened-in-another-application)